# Axes drawn too long on a plot of lines

Tags: pgfplots

I want the axes to be drawn `12.5pt` further than the "widest domain" specified for the two linear functions. This seems to be drawn correctly. Why is the `y`-axis drawn so much longer than specified? The smallest function value is `-8.5` and the biggest function value is `9`. The `y`-axis is drawn more than a centimeter further.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in, height=4in, axis equal=true, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10.5,xmax=15,
    ymin=-8.5,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-8.5:9,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    %xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


%The equation for the line through P and Q is y = (-5/2)*x + 3/2, and the equation for the
%line that is perpendicular bisector for PQ is y = (2/5)x - 43/10. The x-intercept and the
%y-intercept for $\ell$ are A=(43/4,0) and B = (0,-43/10).

\addplot[latex-latex, dashed, domain=-10.5:15] {(2/5)*x - 43/10};
\addplot[latex-latex, domain=-3:4] {(-5/2)*x + 3/2};
\coordinate (P) at (2,-3.5);
\draw [fill] (P) circle [radius=1.5pt];


\coordinate (label_for_k) at (4,-8.5);
\coordinate (label_for_ell) at (15,17/10);

\end{axis}


\draw node[anchor={atan(-5/2)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(label_for_k) +({atan(-5/2)}:0.15)$){\textit{k}};
\draw node[anchor={atan(2/5)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(label_for_ell) +({atan(2/5)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};


%A "pin" is drawn between the label for the intersection of the two lines and the intersection.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P) +({0.5*(atan(-5/2)+atan(2/5))}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(P) +({0.5*(atan(-5/2)+atan(2/5))}:0.75)$){\makebox[0pt][l]{$\left(2, \, \frac{-7}{2}\right)$}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By removing `axis equal=true` you can achived the length you required

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in, height=4in, clip=false, 
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-10.5,xmax=15,
    ymin=-8.5,ymax=9,
    restrict y to domain=-8.5:9,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    %xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


%The equation for the line through P and Q is y = (-5/2)*x + 3/2, and the equation for the
%line that is perpendicular bisector for PQ is y = (2/5)x - 43/10. The x-intercept and the
%y-intercept for $\ell$ are A=(43/4,0) and B = (0,-43/10).

\addplot[latex-latex, dashed, domain=-10.5:15] {(2/5)*x - 43/10};
\addplot[latex-latex, domain=-3:4] {(-5/2)*x + 3/2};
\coordinate (P) at (2,-3.5);
\draw [fill] (P) circle [radius=1.5pt];


\coordinate (label_for_k) at (4,-8.5);
\coordinate (label_for_ell) at (15,17/10);

\end{axis}


\draw node[anchor={atan(-5/2)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(label_for_k) +({atan(-5/2)}:0.15)$){\textit{k}};
\draw node[anchor={atan(2/5)+180}, inner sep=0] at ($(label_for_ell) +({atan(2/5)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};


%A "pin" is drawn between the label for the intersection of the two lines and the intersection.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (P) -- ($(P) +({0.5*(atan(-5/2)+atan(2/5))}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(P) +({0.5*(atan(-5/2)+atan(2/5))}:0.75)$){\makebox[0pt][l]{$\left(2, \, \frac{-7}{2}\right)$}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does removing `axis equal=true` remove the extra lengthening of the `y`-axis?